# opencv2 IOS Framework linker error

Tags: ios, opencv

I have recently compiled the new official opencv2 IOS framework and added to my project. However I have received linker errors while using "split" and "merge" functions.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__ZN2cv5mergeERKSt6vectorINS_3MatESaIS1_EERKNS_12_OutputArrayE", referenced from:
      -[ImageProcessModule paintImage] in ImageProcessModule.o
  "__ZN2cv5splitERKNS_3MatERSt6vectorIS0_SaIS0_EE", referenced from:
      -[ImageProcessModule determineHUELimits] in ImageProcessModule.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was at the trunk version. Use of the official distribution ([OpenCV IOS Framework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.2/opencv2.framework.zip/download)) solved the problem.